# Azure AD B2C sign-in policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

**Scenario**:
Our On-premise AD currently holds our customers/users for on-premise apps.

We starting developing cloud apps for our customers/users and looking at Azure AD/Azure AD B2C for identity management.

We want to use ad connect sync with pass-through authentication to Azure AD because of security requirements.

Customers/users have usernames in form of jane@doe.com in the on-premise - not jane@.com. That means when AD connect sync to Azure AD the username becomes jane@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com and name jane@doe.com.

The Azure AD we sync to is a Azure AD B2C directory.

Question: 
Is it possible to edit the Azure AD B2C sign-in policy to use **name** (jane@doe.com), not username (jane@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com) and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Azure AD B2C sign-in policy to change the synced user name and password.

First, the synced users  are  in Azure AD, not Azure AD B2C.

> Azure AD Connect is not designed to work with Azure AD B2C

Second, if you still want synced username to match your on-premise username, you can refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2523192/user-names-in-office-365--azure--or-intune-don-t-match-the-on-premises) .

Also,if you have not synced from Azure AD Connect, you can use [custom settings in Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom) to let synced username match your on-premise username.